# Aggregating strings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, aggregation

My inputs are in this way :

```
col1   col2 col3
1      a     c
1      b     c
2      c     c
2      d     b
2      e     z
```

And I would like to obtain :

```
col1    col2
1       a, b
2       c, d, e
```

I tried doing this using the virtual layer and in the query builder using array_agg function but QGIS doesn't seem to recognize this feature.

Ideally I would like to obtain this type of results however :

```
col1    col2
1       a:c, b:c
2       c:c, d:b, e:z
```

Comment: Something like `concatenate(concat("col2",':',"col3"), group_by:="col1", concatenator:=', ')` ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I am trying it in the field calculator, but I only get a result for col1 values for which there is only 1 instance (nothing to group), all the rest is null.

Comment: Make sure you choose `Text(string)` as the output field type. If it is set to `Whole number (integer)` the output is null.

Comment: Of course. I double checked that. Also, made the field long enough. Still, only sporadic results.

Comment: OK. It is hard to find the root cause if the results are not definitive. Instead, I will post a Virtual Layer syntax for you to test.

Comment: So far, your tip has been working fine for my needs as I only had one or two columns to merge into one, concataining the contents.
I tried to start from there to concatenate several columns in orther to concatenate the content of each field for one object. I have a dozen fields and I'd like to keep itb that way. My aim is to get, for each object, a concatanation of the content of each field.
I hope my question is clear !
My tries, at best, correctly merge my first column but fail to work for the next ones. Thanks for reading and sharing a solution if anybody already got one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try a Virtual Layer syntax below:

```
SELECT x.col1 AS col1, Group_Concat(x.colx, ', ') AS col2
FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2 || ':' || col3 AS colx
  FROM your_layer 
) x
GROUP BY x.col1
```

In the above example `your_layer` is the part you need to modify.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS expressions and the Aggregate algorithm:

expression used in point 5 (see screen):

`array_to_string (array_agg (col2 || ':' || col3, group_by: = col1))`

[image]